# AWS Lambda w/ API Gateway for Angular back-end?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm still trying to wrap my mind around the limitations of AWS Lambda, especially now that AWS API Gateway opens up a lot of options for serving REST requests with Lambda.

I'm considering building a web app in Angular with Lambda serving as the back-end.

For simple CRUD stuff it seems straightforward enough, but what about authentication? Would I be able to use something like [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) within Lambda to do user authentication?

Comment: Did you ever try this and get it to work?  I can hit my API Gateway endpoints and run lambda functions with Postman, but angular just won't do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can do pretty much anything, just store your session on an AWS hosted database (RDS, Dynamo, etc). But be aware *exactly* you are buying with lambda. It has a lot of trade-offs.

- **Price:** An EC2 server costs a fixed price per month, but lambda has a cost per call. Which is cheaper depends on your usage patterns. Lambda is cheaper when nobody is using your product, EC2 is *most likely* cheaper as usage increases.
- **Scale:** EC2 can scale (in many ways), but it's more "manual" and "chunky" (you can only run 1 server or 2, not 1.5). Lambda has fine-grained scaling. You don't worry about it, but you also have less control over it.
- **Performance:** Lambda is a certain speed, and you have very little control. It may have huge latencies in some cases, as they spin up new containers to handle traffic. EC2 gives you many more options for performance tuning. (Box size, on-box caches, using the latest node.js, removing un-needed services from the box, being able to run strace, etc) You can pay for excess capacity to ensure low latency.
- **Code:** The way you code will be slightly different in Lambda vs EC2. Lambda forces you to obey some conventions that are mostly best practice. But EC2 allows you to violate them for performance, or just speed of development.  Lambda is a "black box" where you have less control and visibility when you need to troubleshoot.
- **Setup:** Lambda is easier to setup and requires less knowledge overall. EC2 requires you to be a sysadmin and understand acronyms like VPC, EBS, VPN, AMI, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Posting this here, since this is the first thread I found when searching for running NodeJS Passport authentication on Lamdba.

Since you can run [Express apps on Lamda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/running-express-applications-on-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/), you really could run Passport on Lambda directly. However, Passport is really middleware specifically for Express, and if you're designing for Lamda in the first place you probably don't want the bloat of Express (Since the API Gateway basically does all that).

As @Jason has mentioned you can utilizing a custom authorizer. This seems pretty straight-forward, but who wants to build all the possible auth methods? That's one of the advantages of Passport, people have already done this for you.

If you're using the [Servlerless Framework](https://serverless.com/), someone has built out the ["Serverless-authentication"](https://github.com/laardee/serverless-authentication) project. This includes modules for many of the standard auth providers: [Facebook](https://github.com/laardee/serverless-authentication-facebook), [Google](https://github.com/laardee/serverless-authentication-google), [Microsoft](https://github.com/laardee/serverless-authentication-microsoft). There is also [a boilerplate for building out more auth providers](https://github.com/laardee/serverless-authentication-boilerplate).

It took me a good bunch of research to run across all of this, so hopefully it will help someone else out.

Answer (score 1):

> but what about authentication?

The most modular approach is to use API Gateway's [Custom Authorizers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) (new since Feb'16) to supply an AWS Lambda function that implement Authentication and Authorization.

I wrote a generic [Custom Authorizer that works with Auth0](https://github.com/jghaines/lambda-auth0-authorizer) a the 3rd-party Single-Sign-On service.

See this question also: [How to - AWS Rest API Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375969/how-to-aws-rest-api-authentication)

> Would I be able to use something like Passport within Lambda to do user authentication?

Not easily. Passport relies on callback URLs which you would have to create and configure.